# Global existence of orthogonal coordinates on 2-manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M^2$ be a 2-manifold and $g$ a Riemannian metric. How do we prove that $\textbf{globally}$ one can write

$$
\begin{equation}
g=g_{11}(dx^1)^2+g_{22}(dx^2)^2.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
$$

To find isothermal coordinates, for instance, one argument is the existence of an integrating factor for some system of differential equations (e.g. Nakahara example 7.9), but this is a local statement. So, is there an argument that guarantees that globally on any 2-Riemannian manifold (we may give in and say that it's also simply connected) we can write (1) ?

(To narrow down the possibilities, I'm particularly interested in the case when the manifold has the topology of a disk, i.e., it's simply connected with boundary.)

Comment: Global coordinate charts need not even exist (the sphere $S^2$ doesn't have any global charts), let alone global charts with such and such property related to the Riemannian metric.

Comment: @peek-a-boo If we say, for instance, that the manifold has the topology of a disk, is the statement true ?

Comment: @DanielKatzner You want to start by considering [Parallelizable Manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold). If I'm remembering correctly, things are a little nicer with $2$-manifolds than $n$ manifolds (assuming your hypothesis of simply-connectedness) since you would actually induce global complex coordinates: the Uniformization Theorem restricts heavily the conformally equivalent structures they could have have, and passage to isothermal coordinates induces a complex structure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem